# Workflow to email after date trigger in SPD 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, office-365

Ive put together view on my Sharepoint list to highlight new users that start within the next week that havent been processed yet.

Im looking to get an email sent out aswell to prompt that there is a request that hasnt been processed that needs to be. Ive begun creating a workflow with the following condition

If Current Item:Phone Status equals New Request
and Current Item:Start Date is greater than or equal to Today
and Current Item:Start Date is less than or equal to Variable: [Today]+7

My concern is that with the workflow, you have the option to start the workflow when item is created ot when its edited but what i want is it to recognise that this item has reached the 7 days until start date bracket THEN run the workflow

I might just be overly cautious but im still new to using SPD2013 and just need piece of mind on how to make this workflow run correctly as i dont want it to send it when the items been created and in practice the item wouldnt have been edited because otherwise it wouldnt be flagging as not complete!

Answer (score 1):

In SPD 2010 we had two actions for this purpose -

- pause workflow till date
- pause workflow for duration.

You can use these to pause the workflow till the desired date and then send the mail.

P.S., too many workflows in a paused state is not my favorite way of doing things.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, so if i run a sharepoint 2010 workflow i should be able to do this? I understand what youre saying about having too many paused workflows but i guess if the works being done correctly then there shouldnt be many cases where the request hasnt been processed. Otherwise is there another suggestion that might not clog the site up as much?

Comment: It's quite possible the actions are present in SP Designer 2013. You'll have to look for them. Also, you would need to create a Designer workflow depending on the version of SharePoint installed - SPD 2010 for SP 2010 and SPD 2013 for SP 2013

Comment: The better option would be to go for scheduled/timer jobs. However, they require a different level of access and are restricted in some organizations.

Comment: Ive had a look at pausing the workflow, am i right in thinking if i create a local variable and name it Current Item:Start Date-7 this will pause the workflow until 7 days prior to the start date?

Comment: Yes. It will, once you place the variable in the 'pause till date' action.

Comment: Sorry, with a local variable, what would i need to name it in order to for it to be Less than or equal toCurrent Item:Start Date-7?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's as much as I can help without trying it myself. Sorry!
Also, For reference: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-HA010376961.aspx